# Prevent trimming spaces between words in webservices

Tags: c#, web-services

I have the below code used in web services.

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Services;

    namespace StringTest
    {
       /// <summary>
       /// Summary description for StringTest
       /// </summary>
       [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
       [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
       [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
       // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
       // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
       public class StringTest : System.Web.Services.WebService
       {

           [WebMethod]

           public string HelloWorld(string str)
           {
               return str;
           }
       }
    }
```

When I provide the input as `Hello  world`, I'm getting the result as `Hello world` (two spaces between the words has been reduced to one). I'm referring an external web service and cannot modify any code in the method definition. How to get the result without any data manipulation?

Comment: How are you calling this method? What tool/code are you using? The code you've shown will not exhibit the problem you're describing by itself.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I'm tested this from .asmx file. This error is not occurring when calling from application.